# kiosk software for multiple PowerPoints

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, kiosk

I need to allow users at a meeting to browse a number of PowerPoint presentations.

My current plan is to save the PowerPoints as `.pps` show files, and have a Firefox install running in kiosk mode that's set to open `.pps` without prompting. (the presentations and their metadata come out of a web application, so having a web interface is appealing to us)

I'd love to have the kiosk close the open `.pps` and return Firefox to its home page after a set amount of inactivity, if possible.

Has anyone does this? Anything to beware of? Better options than I've thought of? I can be reasonably assured that the meeting participants will not be (maliciously) tinkering with any of the PCs.

Answer (score 1):

Try making another `pps` with links to the other ones.

**EDIT**: I tried it, and it works perfectly.
After the linked presentation is finished, it will return the the slide that had the link.

Comment: The PowerPoints are already submitted, along with a lot of metadata, to a web application. I'd prefer to avoid the manual work of creating a container .pps, and I'm not sure if the container would remain open after the presentation .pps was closed.

Comment: +1 for a potential option, though. Cheers. :-)

Comment: In your solution, that should already happen - after the `pps` finishes playing, it will close, and it should return to Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

This might be programming as you will need a timer macro in the pps to enable it to close itself after a certain period of time. Or they could also be programmed to start the FF after a period of time and close it and run itself again after a certain period of time.